# Nearest neighbour upsampling in caffe (pycaffe)

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I am searching for an example, how to upsample a feature map via nearest neighbor in pycaffe. For example, I want to upsample a `[6x6x256]` feature layer to a `[10x10x256]` feature layer. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find something sufficient for my needs so far. I would be happy if someone could give me an example how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out, that you can do upsampling by deconvolving your feature map with a fixed kernel initialized with ones.